# Literal or legend: how do Catholics treat non-Biblical miracles?

Tags: catholicism, miracles

I am aware that I lack expertise on this topic sorry if the question is badly worded.

There are a lot of reported miracles of the saints in Catholicism reported hundreds of years after Jesus' life, some of which are of-a-form like stigmata and some of which are very unusual like St. Denis having his head chopped off and then walking six miles preaching a sermon.

I would like to know how literally Catholic believers and the Catholic church believe these events to be? Are each of them considered a fact? Or are they thought of more as local stories/heroes or stories of moral instruction or even just there to indicate that a particular person was strong in their faith? Is it considered heresy to suggest that these events are not literally true?

Comment: Short answer. Of course the Church and Catholics believe in miracles. Authenticated miracles are required for [Beatification and Canonization](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02364b.htm). Please research also the [miracles at Lourdes](http://en.lourdes-france.org/deepen/cures-and-miracles).

Comment: I should point out that authorities in the Roman Catholic church take pains to research whether these stories are credible or not. Just because the stories are published in a Catholic bookstore doesn't mean they have been vetted by Catholic historians. Plenty of Catholics in a secularized society don't believe in the more sensationalized stories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested read more at http://www.catholicbibleanswers.com and let me know what you think

The Catholic Church does consider many miracles outside the Bible to be from God - they are literal miracles

Maybe the most notable miracles are the Marian apparitions (ie., appearances of Mary the mother of Jesus to many individuals across the globe)

Check out: Our Lady of Lourdes apparitions, Our Lady of Guadalupe (this miracle was how South America converted to Christianity about 500 years ago), Our lady of Fatima, etc

There are also many healing miracles

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites), and
[What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)